# Google authentication in python/flask error: Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Invalid scheme: ('http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback',)

Tags: python, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement a simple login system in my python/flask app with Google auth, but I'm getting this error on the browser:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_request
>
> Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Invalid scheme:
>   ('http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback',)

This is the screen shot of the browser:
[image]

---

Google console credentials are configured like:

```
Authorised JavaScript origins: http://localhost:8080
Authorised redirect URIs: http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback
```

[image]

---

My implementation is based on this gist:
https://gist.github.com/ashish01/2a4a0f9b525096633ca2

My line 15 is configured like:

```
GOOGLE_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI='http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback',
```

And I get this error when I try to access the route '/home'

Does anyone knows why Google are complaining about the scheme and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have invalid chars in your redirect URI

> ('http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback',)

extra **,** on the end.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo. 

There was a typo in the config:


    GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID='123456789-11111111111111111111.apps.googleusercontent.com',

Do you see the commas in the end?.. my bad!